# Pythonic way to move a 2D array into a 5D array? (Family Tree Project)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have a 5D Numpy array representing family trees. The first index represents the family (the Jetsons or the Flintstones), the second is the generation (parents or children), the third is their gender, the fourth is the individual, and the final their attributes (height, weight, age, income).

For example, arr[0,0,1,0,:] would return a 1D-array of Fred Flinstone's attributes, since he is family 0, generation 0, gender 1, individual 0.

The question is: Can I take a 2D Father_Array (containing 3 fathers and 4 of their attributes), and insert it into the 5D Family_Array in a pythonic manner?

I tried:

```
family_array = np.empty((0, 2, 2, 1, 4))
father_array = np.ones((3,4))

family_array = np.append(family_array[:, 0, 0, 0, :], father_array, axis=0)
```

But this returns an array of shape (3,4) rather than (3,2,2,1,4). I want to be able to retrieve father attributes by:

```
family_array[i,0,1,0,:]
```

Where 'i' represents each family (i = 0 for Flintstones, i = 1 for Jetsons, i = 2 for Rubbles, etc)

Answer (score 1):

To create the `family_array` with the correct dimensions, you need to have a 5D array with dimensions (3, 2, 2, 1, 4), where 3 is the number of families, 2 is the number of generations and genders, 1 is the number of individuals (since we're only considering fathers for now), and 4 is the number of attributes.

You can then insert the `father_array` into the `family_array` for the first generation (0) and the male gender (1) as follows:

```py
family_array = np.zeros((3, 2, 2, 1, 4))
father_array = np.ones((3,4))

family_array[:, 0, 1, 0, :] = father_array
```

This will insert `father_array` into the corresponding position of `family_array`, and you'll be able to retrieve the attributes of the fathers using `family_array[i,0,1,0,:]`.